# How to avoid Google Play Console issues related to architecture

Tags: android, flutter, google-play

Google Play Console is showing an error for my app on Pixel 2 x86 virtual device.

> Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113

[image: Google Play Console Issue]

I understand this [architecture](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#what-are-the-supported-target-architectures) is not supported by Flutter.

What can I do?

Is there a way to specify which architectures are valid for my app so that Play Console does not test using unsupported ones? Or should I change something when building a deployment package?

Comment: Did u find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Looks like Google fixed it! Not getting it in the latest release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google fixed this, it is no longer a problem.

See this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/109641)